jdbc connection to mysql mysqld 8.0.37 over SSL
I have one application server and one database server both linux, application server is using tomcat and we are connecting to MySql DB server using JDBC, so far i was not facing any issue as SSL was not enabled on Db server.
Now due to security compliance, connection to mysql db server over SSL is mandatory.
My application server has following java version installed :
java version "1.8.0_201"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_201-b09)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.201-b09, mixed mode)

so far i have followed below process.
I have imported mysql client certificate on application server keystore using below command :
keytool -importcert -keystore /usr/java/default/jre/lib/security/cacerts -storepass 123@123@456 -alias mysqlclient -file client-keystore.cer

it was successfully imported without any error.
Now i am trying to make mysql connection using below connection string.
conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://XX.X.XXX.XX:XXXX/Mydb?verifyServerCertificate=false&useSSL=true&requireSSL=true&enabledTLSProtocols=TLSv1.2","user","pwd");

I am getting following error/exception
com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:165)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:55)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:845)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:420)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:238)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:180)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
        at TestConn_1.main(TestConn_1.java:21)
Caused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.CJCommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:52)
        at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:95)
        at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:140)
        at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createCommunicationsException(ExceptionFactory.java:156)
        at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.negotiateSSLConnection(NativeProtocol.java:367)
        at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeAuthenticationProvider.connect(NativeAuthenticationProvider.java:198)
        at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.connect(NativeProtocol.java:1336)
        at com.mysql.cj.NativeSession.connect(NativeSession.java:153)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:969)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:833)
        ... 6 more
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
        at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
        at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:154)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.recvAlert(SSLSocketImpl.java:2020)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1127)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1367)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1395)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1379)
        at com.mysql.cj.protocol.ExportControlled.performTlsHandshake(ExportControlled.java:206)
        at com.mysql.cj.protocol.StandardSocketFactory.performTlsHandshake(StandardSocketFactory.java:183)
        at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeSocketConnection.performTlsHandshake(NativeSocketConnection.java:91)
        at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.negotiateSSLConnection(NativeProtocol.java:358)

I have tried, possible reason/solutions provided at this
But none of the solutions works for me. Can anyone helps me to get it resolved  ?
I tried with command : java -Djavax.net.debug=SSL TestConn_1
following is output of above command :
System property jdk.tls.client.cipherSuites is set to 'null'
System property jdk.tls.server.cipherSuites is set to 'null'
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_DH_anon_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_DH_anon_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_NULL_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: SSL_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: SSL_DHE_DSS_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_KRB5_WITH_DES_CBC_MD5
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_NULL_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: SSL_DH_anon_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_MD5
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: SSL_DH_anon_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_DH_anon_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_KRB5_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_KRB5_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_KRB5_EXPORT_WITH_DES_CBC_40_MD5
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_KRB5_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_MD5
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: SSL_DH_anon_WITH_RC4_128_MD5
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_NULL_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_NULL_SHA256
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: SSL_DH_anon_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_anon_WITH_NULL_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: SSL_DHE_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_anon_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_KRB5_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: SSL_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_KRB5_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_anon_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: SSL_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_MD5
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_KRB5_EXPORT_WITH_DES_CBC_40_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_KRB5_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_MD5
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_anon_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_KRB5_WITH_RC4_128_MD5
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_NULL_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_anon_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: SSL_DH_anon_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: SSL_RSA_WITH_NULL_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_DH_anon_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: SSL_RSA_WITH_NULL_MD5
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_DH_anon_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_DH_anon_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV
trigger seeding of SecureRandom
done seeding SecureRandom
Allow unsafe renegotiation: false
Allow legacy hello messages: true
Is initial handshake: true
Is secure renegotiation: false
%% No cached client session
update handshake state: client_hello[1]
upcoming handshake states: server_hello[2]
*** ClientHello, TLSv1.2
RandomCookie:  GMT: 1710342910 bytes = { 239, 40, 23, 61, 55, 137, 146, 137, 108, 77, 233, 243, 159, 200, 107, 72, 228, 143, 110, 111, 186, 249, 104, 193, 70, 179, 189, 4 }
Session ID:  {}
Cipher Suites: [TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256]
Compression Methods:  { 0 }
Extension elliptic_curves, curve names: {secp256r1, secp384r1, secp521r1, sect283k1, sect283r1, sect409k1, sect409r1, sect571k1, sect571r1, secp256k1}
Extension ec_point_formats, formats: [uncompressed]
Extension signature_algorithms, signature_algorithms: SHA512withECDSA, SHA512withRSA, SHA384withECDSA, SHA384withRSA, SHA256withECDSA, SHA256withRSA, SHA256withDSA, SHA224withECDSA, SHA224withRSA, SHA224withDSA, SHA1withECDSA, SHA1withRSA, SHA1withDSA
Extension extended_master_secret
Extension renegotiation_info, renegotiated_connection: <empty>
***
main, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 202
main, READ: TLSv1.2 Alert, length = 2
main, RECV TLSv1.2 ALERT:  fatal, handshake_failure
main, called closeSocket()
main, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:165)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:55)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:845)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:420)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:238)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:180)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
        at TestConn_1.main(TestConn_1.java:21)
Caused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.CJCommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:52)
        at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:95)
        at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:140)
        at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createCommunicationsException(ExceptionFactory.java:156)
        at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.negotiateSSLConnection(NativeProtocol.java:367)
        at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeAuthenticationProvider.connect(NativeAuthenticationProvider.java:198)
        at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.connect(NativeProtocol.java:1336)
        at com.mysql.cj.NativeSession.connect(NativeSession.java:153)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:969)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:833)
        ... 6 more
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
        at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
        at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:154)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.recvAlert(SSLSocketImpl.java:2020)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1127)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1367)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1395)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1379)
        at com.mysql.cj.protocol.ExportControlled.performTlsHandshake(ExportControlled.java:206)
        at com.mysql.cj.protocol.StandardSocketFactory.performTlsHandshake(StandardSocketFactory.java:183)
        at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeSocketConnection.performTlsHandshake(NativeSocketConnection.java:91)
        at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.negotiateSSLConnection(NativeProtocol.java:358)

and output of java -Djavax.net.debug=SSL,keymanager,trustmanager,ssl:handshake TestConn_1 is below:
System property jdk.tls.client.cipherSuites is set to 'null'
System property jdk.tls.server.cipherSuites is set to 'null'
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_DH_anon_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_DH_anon_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_NULL_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: SSL_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: SSL_DHE_DSS_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_KRB5_WITH_DES_CBC_MD5
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_NULL_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: SSL_DH_anon_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_MD5
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: SSL_DH_anon_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_DH_anon_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_KRB5_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_KRB5_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_KRB5_EXPORT_WITH_DES_CBC_40_MD5
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_KRB5_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_MD5
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: SSL_DH_anon_WITH_RC4_128_MD5
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_NULL_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_NULL_SHA256
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: SSL_DH_anon_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_anon_WITH_NULL_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: SSL_DHE_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_anon_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_KRB5_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: SSL_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_KRB5_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_anon_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: SSL_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_MD5
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_KRB5_EXPORT_WITH_DES_CBC_40_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_KRB5_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_MD5
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_anon_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_KRB5_WITH_RC4_128_MD5
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_NULL_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_anon_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: SSL_DH_anon_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: SSL_RSA_WITH_NULL_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_DH_anon_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: SSL_RSA_WITH_NULL_MD5
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_DH_anon_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_DH_anon_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV
trigger seeding of SecureRandom
done seeding SecureRandom
Allow unsafe renegotiation: false
Allow legacy hello messages: true
Is initial handshake: true
Is secure renegotiation: false
%% No cached client session
update handshake state: client_hello[1]
upcoming handshake states: server_hello[2]
*** ClientHello, TLSv1.2
RandomCookie:  GMT: 1710397350 bytes = { 153, 103, 91, 216, 40, 55, 86, 40, 49, 94, 194, 36, 238, 12, 86, 77, 81, 95, 56, 238, 172, 147, 237, 84, 163, 101, 223, 94 }
Session ID:  {}
Cipher Suites: [TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256]
Compression Methods:  { 0 }
Extension elliptic_curves, curve names: {secp256r1, secp384r1, secp521r1, sect283k1, sect283r1, sect409k1, sect409r1, sect571k1, sect571r1, secp256k1}
Extension ec_point_formats, formats: [uncompressed]
Extension signature_algorithms, signature_algorithms: SHA512withECDSA, SHA512withRSA, SHA384withECDSA, SHA384withRSA, SHA256withECDSA, SHA256withRSA, SHA256withDSA, SHA224withECDSA, SHA224withRSA, SHA224withDSA, SHA1withECDSA, SHA1withRSA, SHA1withDSA
Extension extended_master_secret
Extension renegotiation_info, renegotiated_connection: <empty>
***
main, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 202
main, READ: TLSv1.2 Alert, length = 2
main, RECV TLSv1.2 ALERT:  fatal, handshake_failure
main, called closeSocket()
main, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:165)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:55)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:845)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:420)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:238)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:180)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
        at TestConn_1.main(TestConn_1.java:21)
Caused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.CJCommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:52)
        at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:95)
        at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:140)
        at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createCommunicationsException(ExceptionFactory.java:156)
        at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.negotiateSSLConnection(NativeProtocol.java:367)
        at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeAuthenticationProvider.connect(NativeAuthenticationProvider.java:198)
        at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.connect(NativeProtocol.java:1336)
        at com.mysql.cj.NativeSession.connect(NativeSession.java:153)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:969)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:833)
        ... 6 more
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
        at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
        at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:154)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.recvAlert(SSLSocketImpl.java:2020)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1127)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1367)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1395)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1379)
        at com.mysql.cj.protocol.ExportControlled.performTlsHandshake(ExportControlled.java:206)
        at com.mysql.cj.protocol.StandardSocketFactory.performTlsHandshake(StandardSocketFactory.java:183)
        at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeSocketConnection.performTlsHandshake(NativeSocketConnection.java:91)
        at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.negotiateSSLConnection(NativeProtocol.java:358)


show variables like 'ssl_%'; (as root) check out OK? Also worth doing -Djavax.net.debug=SSL client-side

Yes, SSL is enabled on Mysql server.  for Djavax.net.debug=SSL where to check logs  ?

That should go to your regular log file

Error are same as in question...no additional information

How did you apply that system variable? Did you restart Tomcat?

export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_201-amd64/lib:/opt/Logs:/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_201-amd64/lib/mysql-connector-j-9.0.0.jar .....then javac filename.java .....then java filename -Djavax.net.debug=SSL

I thought -Djavax.net.debug=SSL gives a lot more information about the SSL handshake, allowing more granular insight into where the failure occurs.

Put -Djavax.net.debug=SSL directly after java. I thought you were using Tomcat? That command you posted isn't using it

@g00se, yes at the end of the issue, we are going to use tomcat, for testing/troubleshooting, have create sample java file, i edited my question to place output of java java -Djavax.net.debug=all TestConn_1

Can you rerun with the following VM arguments and share the log output: -Djavax.net.debug=SSL,keymanager,trustmanager,ssl:handshake

@Hakan54, output added in question

Hmm, I cannot find out why it is failing based on the logs... In the past I had also issues with mysql db connector and I configured it with custom ssl configuration, which might also do the trick for you. But I am not sure... I have an example here: https://github.com/Hakky54/java-tutorials/blob/main/bypassing-overruling-ssl-configuration/src/main/java/nl/altindag/ssl/App.java

@Hakan54, I tried "Test connection" option in workbench from my local machine to same db server and it shows "SSL : enabled with TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256" and connection was successful, in above logs cipher TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 is not there,  now i am checking to add cipher in TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 in existing java installed on app server. will update

any idea about how to enable specific cipher suite in java ?
